# How to get first element in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like below where the first element is the id and the other is a string:

```
[(1, u'abc'), (2, u'def')]
```

I want to create a list of ids only from this list of tuples as below:

```
[1,2]
```

I'll use this list in `__in` so it needs to be a list of integer values.

Answer (score 350, accepted):

```
>>> a = [(1, u'abc'), (2, u'def')]
>>> [i[0] for i in a]
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 101):

Use the zip function to decouple elements:

```
>>> inpt = [(1, u'abc'), (2, u'def')]
>>> unzipped = zip(*inpt)
>>> print unzipped
[(1, 2), (u'abc', u'def')]
>>> print list(unzipped[0])
[1, 2]
```

**Edit** (@BradSolomon):
The above works for Python 2.x, where `zip` returns a list.

In Python 3.x, `zip` returns an iterator and the following is equivalent to the above:

```
>>> print(list(list(zip(*inpt))[0]))
[1, 2]
```

Comment: does this need a separate import?

Comment: @JuliandotNut No, it's a built-in function. (in Python 2.x)

Comment: Why is the second cast to `list` necessary?

Comment: I know this wasn't the accepted answer, but this helped me immensely in the task I was just doing. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 28):

I was thinking that it might be useful to compare the runtimes of the different approaches so I made a benchmark (using [simple_benchmark](https://pypi.org/project/simple-benchmark/) library)

**I) Benchmark having tuples with 2 elements**
[image]

As you may expect to select the first element from tuples by index `0` shows to be the fastest solution very close to the unpacking solution by expecting exactly 2 values

```
import operator
import random

from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder

b = BenchmarkBuilder()



@b.add_function()
def rakesh_by_index(l):
    return [i[0] for i in l]


@b.add_function()
def wayneSan_zip(l):
    return list(list(zip(*l))[0])


@b.add_function()
def bcattle_itemgetter(l):
     return list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), l))


@b.add_function()
def ssoler_upacking(l):
    return [idx for idx, val in l]

@b.add_function()
def kederrack_unpacking(l):
    return [f for f, *_ in l]



@b.add_arguments('Number of tuples')
def argument_provider():
    for exp in range(2, 21):
        size = 2**exp
        yield size, [(random.choice(range(100)), random.choice(range(100))) for _ in range(size)]


r = b.run()
r.plot()
```

**II) Benchmark having tuples with 2 or more elements**
[image]

```
import operator
import random

from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder

b = BenchmarkBuilder()

@b.add_function()
def kederrack_unpacking(l):
    return [f for f, *_ in l]


@b.add_function()
def rakesh_by_index(l):
    return [i[0] for i in l]


@b.add_function()
def wayneSan_zip(l):
    return list(list(zip(*l))[0])


@b.add_function()
def bcattle_itemgetter(l):
     return list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), l))


@b.add_arguments('Number of tuples')
def argument_provider():
    for exp in range(2, 21):
        size = 2**exp
        yield size, [tuple(random.choice(range(100)) for _
                     in range(random.choice(range(2, 100)))) for _ in range(size)]

from pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 12, 7

r = b.run()
r.plot()
```

Answer (score 25):

do you mean something like this?

```
new_list = [ seq[0] for seq in yourlist ]
```

What you actually have is a list of `tuple` objects, not a list of sets (as your original question implied).  If it is actually a list of sets, then *there is no first element* because sets have no order.

Here I've created a flat list because generally that seems more useful than creating a list of 1 element tuples.  However, you can easily create a list of 1 element tuples by just replacing `seq[0]` with `(seq[0],)`.

Comment: I tried it. It gives this error: `int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'QuerySet'`

Comment: @wasimbhalli -- `int()` is nowhere in my solution, so the exception you're seeing must come later on in the code.

Comment: I've updated the question, I need to use this list later in `__in` for filtering data

Comment: what is `__in`? -- Based on the example input you've given, this will create a list of integers.  However, if your list of tuples doesn't start with integers, then you won't get integers and you'll need to make them integers via `int`, or try to figure out why your first element can't be converted to an integer.

Comment: Does `new_list = [ seq[0] for seq in yourlist if type(seq[0]) == int]` work?

Comment: `User.objects.filter(id__in=` and the list of ids will be used after equal sign

Comment: @pROPs -- these days `type(...) == int` is better replaced with `isinstance(...,int)`

Comment: @wasimbhalli -- What is `User.objects.filter`?  At this point, you should probably re-tag your question with whatever package that came from and show example code of what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 19):

This is what [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) is for.

```
>>> a = [(1, u'abc'), (2, u'def')]
>>> import operator
>>> b = map(operator.itemgetter(0), a)
>>> b
[1, 2]
```

The `itemgetter` statement *returns a function* that returns the element at the index that you specify. It's exactly the same as writing

```
>>> b = map(lambda x: x[0], a)
```

But I find that `itemgetter` is a clearer and [more explicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3).

This is handy for making compact sort statements. For example,

```
>>> c = sorted(a, key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
>>> c
[(2, u'def'), (1, u'abc')]
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use "tuple unpacking":

```
>>> my_list = [(1, 'abc'), (2, 'def')]
>>> my_ids = [idx for idx, val in my_list]
>>> my_ids
[1, 2]
```

At iteration time each tuple is unpacked and its values are set to the variables `idx` and `val`.

```
>>> x = (1, 'abc')
>>> idx, val = x
>>> idx
1
>>> val
'abc'
```

Answer (score 8):

if the tuples are unique then this can work

```
>>> a = [(1, u'abc'), (2, u'def')]
>>> a
[(1, u'abc'), (2, u'def')]
>>> dict(a).keys()
[1, 2]
>>> dict(a).values()
[u'abc', u'def']
>>>
```

Comment: This will lose the order.  It may work with `ordereddict`, though.

Comment: if 2 or more tuples have the same first element than your solution will not work

Answer (score 8):

From a performance point of view, in python3.X

- `[i[0] for i in a]` and `list(zip(*a))[0]` are equivalent
- they are faster than `list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), a))`

**Code**

```
import timeit


iterations = 100000
init_time = timeit.timeit('''a = [(i, u'abc') for i in range(1000)]''', number=iterations)/iterations
print(timeit.timeit('''a = [(i, u'abc') for i in range(1000)]\nb = [i[0] for i in a]''', number=iterations)/iterations - init_time)
print(timeit.timeit('''a = [(i, u'abc') for i in range(1000)]\nb = list(zip(*a))[0]''', number=iterations)/iterations - init_time)
```

**output**

3.491014136001468e-05

3.422205176000717e-05

Answer (score 5):

I'd prefer zipping this way:

```
>>> lst = [(1, u'abc'), (2, u'def')]
>>> new, _ = zip(*lst)
>>> new
(1, 2)
>>>
```

Or if you don't know how many extra values there are:

```
>>> new, *_ = zip(*lst)
>>> new
(1, 2)
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

when I ran (as suggested above):

```
>>> a = [(1, u'abc'), (2, u'def')]
>>> import operator
>>> b = map(operator.itemgetter(0), a)
>>> b
```

instead of returning:

```
[1, 2]
```

I received this as the return:

```
<map at 0xb387eb8>
```

I found I had to use list():

```
>>> b = list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), a))
```

to successfully return a list using this suggestion. That said, I'm happy with this solution, thanks. (tested/run using Spyder, iPython console, Python v3.6)

Answer (score 4):

you can [unpack](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) your tuples and get only the first element using a list comprehension:

```
l = [(1, u'abc'), (2, u'def')]
[f for f, *_ in l]
```

**output:**

```
[1, 2]
```

this will work no matter how many elements you have in a tuple:

```
l = [(1, u'abc'), (2, u'def', 2, 4, 5, 6, 7)]
[f for f, *_ in l]
```

**output:**

```
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

I wondered why nobody suggested to use numpy, but now after checking i understand. It is maybe not the best for mixed type arrays.

**This would be a solution in numpy:**

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a = np.asarray([(1, u'abc'), (2, u'def')])
>>> a[:, 0].astype(int).tolist()
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

To get an element of a list or tuple you can iterate through a list or tuple

```py
a = [(1, u'abc'), (2, u'def')]

list1 = [a[i][0] for i in range(len(a))]

print(list1)
```

Comment: Iterating a list by iterating an index is very rarely used in Python because there's faster and clearer ways to go about it. Whenever you see it, challenge yourself to refactor without it.

Answer (score 0):

Those are tuples, not sets. You can do this:

```
l1 = [(1, u'abc'), (2, u'def')]
l2 = [(tup[0],) for tup in l1]
l2
>>> [(1,), (2,)]
```

Comment: Not really what is being asked

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert to a nested of the list, the answer will be:

```
a = [(1, u'abc'), (2, u'def')]
print([list(i[0]) for i in a])
```

output:

```
[[1], [2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using list comprehension.

```
og_list = [(1, u'abc'), (2, u'def')]
list_of_keys = [key for key, _ in og_list]
```

output

```
[1,2]
```

Answer (score -1):

another simple suggestion if you need to convert to a nested of the tuple, and  all elements inside the list the answer will be:

```
s=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    s.append(a[i][0])
print(s)
```

Output:

```
[(1),(2)]
```