# How to make a new list of first elements from existing list of lists

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list below. I need to use it to create a new list with only country names.
How do I loop `x` in order to have a list of country names?

```
x = [["UK", "LONDON", "EUROPE"],
     ["US", "WASHINGTON", "AMERICA"],
     ["EG", "CAIRO", "AFRICA"],
     ["JP", "TOKYO", "ASIA"]]
```

The outcome should look like

```
UK
US
EG
JP
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get first element in a list of tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142133/how-to-get-first-element-in-a-list-of-tuples)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two ways

Using a for loop

```
countries = []

for e in x:
 countries.append(e[0])
```

or with list comprehensions, which would be in most cases the better option

```
countries = [e[0] for e in x]
```

Furthermore, if your data source is a generator (which it isn't in this case), or if you're doing some expensive processing on each element (not this case either), you could use a `generator expression` by changing the square brackets `[]` for parenthesis `()`

```
countries = (e[0] for e in x)
```

This will compute on demand the elements, and if the data source is too long or a generator will also reduce the memory footprint compared to a list comprehension.

Answer (score 4):

The most readable way is probably:

```
>>> data = [["UK", "LONDON", "EUROPE"],
            ["US", "WASHINGTON", "AMERICA"],
            ["EG", "CAIRO", "AFRICA"],
            ["JP","TOKYO","ASIA"]]
>>> countries = [country for country, city, continent in data]
>>> countries 
['UK', 'US', 'EG', 'JP']
```

This [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) makes it clear what the three values in each item from `data` are, and which will be in the output, whereas the index `0` doesn't tell the reader much at all.

Answer (score 1):

As cities `LONDON`, `WASHINGTON`, `CAIRO`, `TOKYO` are present in 1st position(starting from 0) on list items. So get all 1st item from the list items by list compression.

e.g.

```
>>> x= [["UK", "LONDON", "EUROPE"],["US", "WASHINGTON", "AMERICA"],["EG", "CAIRO", "AFRICA"],["JP","TOKYO","ASIA"]]
>>> [i[1] for i in x]
['LONDON', 'WASHINGTON', 'CAIRO', 'TOKYO']
>>>
```

same for countries:

```
>>> [i[0] for i in x]
['UK', 'US', 'EG', 'JP']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can find yourself assuming the data `x` always contains the list in form of `[COUNTRY, CITYNAME, CONTINENT]`, you can retrieve every first items from each list in `x` like below:

```
countries = []
for country, cityname, continent in x:
    countries.append(country)
```

You can shorten above using list comprehension.

```
>>> countries = [country for country, cityname, continent in x]
```

Of course you can access the value via an index.

```
>>> countries = [lst[0] for lst in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also unpack the list and append to new list:

```
x= [["UK", "LONDON", "EUROPE"],["US", "WASHINGTON", "AMERICA"],["EG", "CAIRO", "AFRICA"],["JP","TOKYO","ASIA"]]

countries = []

for a,b,c in x:
    countries.append(a)
```