# How to get 2nd elements from tuples in Python?

Tags: python, tuples

I would like to have an array with all 2nd elements for which the first element is equal to 'tuple1elem1'. How can I do this efficiently? I have around 500 tuples.

**Tuples:**

```
(('tuple1elem1', 'tuple1elem2'), ('tuple2elem1', 'tuple2elem2'), ('tuple3elem1', 'tuple3elem2'))
```

**What I would like to have:**

```
array = ['tuple1elem2']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get first element in a list of tuples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142133/how-to-get-first-element-in-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: In your example, there are no second elements which are Hello World?

Comment: @merlin2011 I've updated the question.

Comment: @Vallentin It's not the same thing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a list comprehension with a filter.

```
myList = [...]
output = [x[1] for x in myList if x[0] == 'tuple1elem1']
```

Answer (score 1):

You access elements from a tuple mostly the same way as elements of a list. You could for example unpack them:

```
>>> bigtuple = (('tuple1elem1', 'tuple1elem2'), ('tuple2elem1', 'tuple2elem2'), ('tuple3elem1', 'tuple3elem2'))
>>> array = [ele2 for ele1, ele2 in bigtuple if ele1 == "tuple1elem1"]
['tuple1elem2']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a fast way to get and add only 2nd elements from list of tuples:

```
import numpy as np 

tuples_list = [(0, 10), (0, 20), (0, 30)]
fast_tuples_add = np.array(tuples_list) + (0, 9) # fast tuples add

fast_tuples_add
array([[ 0, 19],[ 0, 29], [ 0, 39]])
```

Hope this helps