# making python algorithm to accept input values

Tags: python, algorithm

So I have that algorithm for breadth first and depth first search in python. I want to change it that instead of the parents variable which keeps the nodes, I want the values to be introduced by the user by an input and I dont know how to do that..

```html
def DFS_dist_from_node(query_node, parents):
    """Return dictionary containing distances of parent GO nodes from the query"""
    result = {}
    stack = []
    stack.append( (query_node, 0) )
    while len(stack) > 0:
        print("stack=", stack)
        node, dist = stack.pop()
        result[node] = dist
        if node in parents:
            for parent in parents[node]:
                # Get the first member of each tuple, see 
                # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142133/how-to-get-first-element-in-a-list-of-tuples
                stack_members = [x[0] for x in stack]
                if parent not in stack_members:
                    stack.append( (parent, dist+1) )
    return result
    
def BFS_dist_from_node(query_node, parents):
    """Return dictionary containing minimum distances of parent GO nodes from the query"""
    result = {}
    queue = []
    queue.append( (query_node, 0) )
    while queue:
        print("queue=", queue)
        node, dist = queue.pop(0)
        result[node] = dist
        if node in parents: # If the node *has* parents
            for parent in parents[node]:
                # Get the first member of each tuple, see 
                # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142133/how-to-get-first-element-in-a-list-of-tuples
                queue_members = [x[0] for x in queue]
                if parent not in result and parent not in queue_members: # Don't visit a second time
                    queue.append( (parent, dist+1) )
    return result
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    parents = dict()
    parents = {'N1': ['N2', 'N3', 'N4'], 'N3': ['N6', 'N7'], 'N4': ['N3'], 'N5': ['N4', 'N8'], 'N6': ['N13'],
               'N8': ['N9'], 'N9': ['N11'], 'N10': ['N7', 'N9'], 'N11': ['N14'], 'N12': ['N5']}

    print("Depth-first search:")
    dist = DFS_dist_from_node('N1', parents)
    print(dist)
    
    print("Breadth-first search:")
    dist = BFS_dist_from_node('N1', parents)
    print(dist)
```

Answer (score 2):

To take user input during execution of the script, look into [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) and [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).

To take input before the script starts i.e. as command line arguments, take a look at how to use [`sys.argv()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm) and [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html)