# How to match against tuples using Python FuzzyWuzzy library?

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy

I am using FuzzyWuzzy to match a string against tuples contains two strings. For example:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, process
query = "cat"
animals = [('cat','owner1'),('dog','owner3'),('lizard','owner45')]
result = process.extractOne(query, animals, scorer=fuzz.ratio)
```

This code returns an error because the list being compared to, `animals` , is not a list of strings. I would only like to compare to the 1st item in the tuple. What I would like to be returned is: `(('cat','owner1), 100)` because it is a 100% match.

The below code works, outputting `('cat', 100)` but I need the other part of the tuple.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, process
query = "cat"
animals = ["cat","dog",'lizard']
result = process.extractOne(query, lex, scorer=fuzz.ratio)
print(result)
```

Any ideas?

edit: I know that I can get a list of 1st elements with a list comprehension, but for memory and speed reasons, I would like to do this without creating a new list, because I am working with large data sets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get first element in a list of tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142133/how-to-get-first-element-in-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: I'm asking a different question, see the edit

Answer (score 1):

From your list of tuples you can create a sub-list containing only the first item of each tuple by using a list comprehension.

```
>>> animal_owners = [('cat','owner1'),('dog','owner3'),('lizard','owner45')]
>>> [ao[0] for ao in animal_owners]
['cat', 'dog', 'lizard']
```

With this technique you can substitute the second expression where you only need the animals while leaving the original list alone.

Comment: This is true, but I'm looking for  a way to do it without creating a new list.

Answer (score 1):

I know the post is older, but this is an issue I just had to contend with and found a way to do it! If you look at its signature:

```
process.extractOne(
     query, 
     choices, 
     processor: function=function, 
     scorer:function=function, 
     score_cutoff: int=0
)
```

you can utilize the processor function to return the value each tuple you want to be analyzed. For example, say you have a list of company names and their ticker symbols in tuples, and want to get the closest match based on the company name:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

def get_company_name(tup):
    return tup[0]

choices = [
    ('Apple, Inc.', 'AAPL'), 
    ('Google, Inc.', 'GOOGL'), 
    ('Tesla, Inc.', 'TSLA')
]

closest_match = process.extractOne("apple", choices, processor=get_company_name)
```

and then the script will return a tuple with the best match tuple and the pct match:

`(('Apple, Inc.', 'AAPL'), 100)`