# Slice from list of tuples

Tags: python

I've made a list of tuples (each represents a 2D point), and then I want to plot it by using pyplot. So my problem is that I can't get only x coordinats by slicing the list. Here is the code I'm using

```
points = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
plt.plot(points[:][0], points[:][1], 'o')
```

If I'd like to print

```
in:  print(points[:][0])
out: (1, 2)
```

Do you have any idea how to get list of first tuples element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transpose/Unzip Function (inverse of zip)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/transpose-unzip-function-inverse-of-zip)

Comment: This can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142133/how-to-get-first-element-in-a-list-of-tuples

Comment: Literally: get the first element of each tuple: `[x for x, y in points]`, and similarly for `y`.

Comment: @ForceBru works like charm, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Legolando, you're welcome! Of course, that's a bit too repetitive, and you can also get a pair of nice tuples like this: `X, Y = zip(*points)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution by @ForceBru

```
points = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
x = [p[0] for p in points]
y = [p[1] for p in points]
```

Or much easier way (x, y are now tuples)

```
x, y = zip(*points)
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do, is a comprehension list like this one:

```
points = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
x_coordinats = [x[0] for x in points]
y_coordinats = [y[0] for y in points]
```