# Extract item from a list of tuples in Python

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of tuples as follows. An need a list of tuples containing pair of elements starts with different letter.

```
# The given list:

list = [('A2', 'A1'), ('A4', 'A3'), ('B2', 'B4'), ('B2', 'B3'), ('B1', 'B5'), ('B5', 'A1'), ('R1', 'R2'), ('R1', 'R6'), ('R1', 'A2'), ('R1', 'C3'), ('R2', 'R1'), ('R2', 'R6')]

# Required list:

new_list = [('R1', 'A2'), ('R1', 'C3'), ('B5', 'A1')]
```

Comment: what about `(A1, C3)`  what is the logic behicnd the output?

Comment: Is this element exist in 'list'? Logic is both element can't have items with same letter like (A, A), (B, B), (C, C) and (R, R). It can be random pair with different letter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get first element in a list of tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142133/how-to-get-first-element-in-a-list-of-tuples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using list comprehension:

```
spam = [('A2', 'A1'), ('A4', 'A3'), ('B2', 'B4'), ('B2', 'B3'), ('B1', 'B5'), ('B5', 'A1'), ('R1', 'R2'), ('R1', 'R6'), ('R1', 'A2'), ('R1', 'C3'), ('R2', 'R1'), ('R2', 'R6')]
eggs = [(ele1, ele2) for (ele1, ele2) in spam if ele1[0] != ele2[0]]
print(eggs)
```

output

```
[('B5', 'A1'), ('R1', 'A2'), ('R1', 'C3')]
```

note, you should not use `list` as name. It is built-in function.

Comment: Thanks! I shouldn't have use "list" here. But in code I didn't used "list" as variable.

Answer (score 0):

A simple comprehension will do:

```
new_lst = [(x, y) for x, y in lst if x[0] != y[0]]
```

Also do not call any variable `list`. It shadows the built-in type.