# Creating a List in Python From SQL List

Tags: python, sql, project

```
def makeModels():
    make = "Acura"
    models = []
    for model in (cursor.execute('select model from Car where make like ' + "'{}'".format(make))):
        models.append(str(model))
```

I get in Return:

```
('CL', )
('EL', ) 
('ILX', )
('Integra', )
('MDX', )
('NSX', )
('RDX', )
('RL', )
('RLX', )
('RSX', )
('TL', )
('TLX', )
('TSX', )
('ZDX', )
```

Now This is going into a ComboBox and I  I cant have it look like this. I have Class With the same info So my main question is how can I change the format.. What i understand is when you pull something from SQL its and object.

Comment: Can you specify the output format?

Comment: 1) Do not pass parameters in this way, use bind variables instead. 2) `cursor.fetchmany()` returns list of tuples, so just transform it to list of strings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get first element in a list of tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142133/how-to-get-first-element-in-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: @astentx could you explain to me or send me a link on how to use fetchmany?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def makeModels():
    make = "Acura"
    query = 'select model from Car where make like {}'.format(make))
    cursor.execute(query)

    models = [list(i)[0] for i in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Comment: could you explain how I would use this to get a specific query?

Comment: I edited my answer according to your query hope this works for you. @balderman already explained how the query return and so on.

Answer (score 1):

just by changing

`models.append(str(model))` -->  `models.append(model[0])`

Comment: this worked, why does it work if you could explain

Comment: I am glad it worked. The query return a collection of tuple. Each tuple contains one element at offset 0. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it works for you.